# With field coefficients homology and cohomology coincide

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

With field coefficients the universal coefficients theorem takes the form:
$$H^n(X;F)=Hom_{F-modules}(H_n(X;F),F)$$.
Now in all computations I have seen with field coefficients we have
$$H^n(X;F)=H_n(X;F)$$. Is this true for any field or just for specific fields that we are usually working with, so my question can be reformulated as follows: for which fields $F$ do we have that $Hom_{F-modules}(H_n(X;F),F)=H_n(X;F)$? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, why are you writing $\hom_{F-modules}(H_n(X;F),F)$? UCT implies $$H^n(X;F)=\hom_{F}(H_n(X;F),F)$$.

Now, every $F$-module is a $F$-vector space and dual of a (finite dimensional) vector space is isomorphic to itself. So, $H^n(X;F)=\hom_F(H_n(X;F),F)=H_n(X;F)$, whenever $H_n(X;F)$ has finite rank.

For the infinite rank case see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/892081/54151) SE post.

Comment: I'm writing so to say that it is the set of  $F-$module homomorphisms from the $F-$module $H_n(X;F)$ to the $F-$module $F$. This is to differentiate it from group homomorphism or any other less structure so we need homomorphisms that respect $F-$module structure. If this is what you mean buy your simpler notation by putting $F$ instead of $F-$modules ?

Comment: Also $H_n(X;F)$ is an $F-$ module so when you talk about finite **rank**, you mean finite **dimension** as an $F-$vector space ?

Comment: Also i don't understand your sentence "and dual of a (finite dimensional ) vector space is isomorphic to itself" could you please explain what do you mean ?

Comment: I meant to say rank of the module, which in this case is same as the dimension of the vector space.

Comment: As for your second comment, that statement is a fact from linear algebra. Also for an $F$-vector space $V$, $\hom_F(V,F)$ is same as $V^*$, the dual space.

Comment: Ok i see what you mean now. you are saying that a finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to its dual space. Here our vector space is $H_n(X,F)$ which when finite dimensional becomes isomorphic to its dual space $hom_F(H_n(X,F),F)$. Thank you so much!!